# SQL Server Profiler, ObjectName column, 'Split'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

What is the meaning of `ObjectName` column in SQL Server Profiler?

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173882(v=sql.80).aspx gives rather concise definition.

For the records that are interesting to me it's either blank -- when executing statement -- or it contains a stored procedure name. But I just recently noticed that it might also contain 'Split' as a value.

What is the meaning of such a record (entry in Profiler) then?

Comment: Presumably you have an object called `Split`. Quite likely a table valued function that converts a delimited string to a table.

Comment: (This is meant as a continuation of Martin's comment:) Try `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'Split'` and see if it rings the bell.

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed I have a function `Split` doing what you wrote. It's invoked within stored procedure so I have 5 entries with the same TextData column for each invocation of stored procedure (4 records for 4 invocations of split, 1 record for sp itself) -- and that was the source of my confusion.